# deploy fail on kubernetes: kubectl apply fail

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

I have tried to run this YAML fine, but I am getting the below issue
1 master `2` nodes has been configured and  I ran kubectl get nodes output looks fine

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/deployment.yaml
```

then I have downloaded the file locally and tried, but again same error

`Error` from server (Forbidden) :

> deployments.extensions "nginx-deployment" is 
>   forbidden: User "system:node:master" cannot get deployments.extensions in the 
>     namespace "default"
>     root@master:~#

Please assist me to resolve the issue

Comment: Seems you're executing it from the machine where your control plane runs, did you try it from outside of the cluster yet?

Comment: root@master:/home# kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/nginx-deployment.yaml
error: unable to read URL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/nginx-deployment.yaml", server reported 404 Not Found, status code=404

Comment: The correct URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/nginx-deployment.yaml

Answer (score 3):

This is a RBAC restriction about which you can read on [Kubernetes - Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) docs.

You want to create your own `ServiceAccount` then `Role` and then bind them 
together using `RoleBinding`.

> ServiceAccount example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: some-name
  namespace: my-name
```

> Role example

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: some-name
  namespace: my-name
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    verbs: ["get","list","patch","update"]
```

> RoleBinding example

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: some-name
  namespace: my-name
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: some-name
    namespace: my-name
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: some-name
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

There are examples online which you can find.